# Why did not work latest method in Laravel 5.6 app?

Tags: php, laravel, search, pagination

working with laravel 5.6 and in my app I have searching input in index blade using algolia.
index.blade.php

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ url('search') }}">
      {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button class="btn btn-info">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <br> 

@forelse( $vehicles as $vehicule )


                    @if( $vehicule->uploads->count() > 0 )
                        <a href="{{ route('vehicles.show', $vehicule->id) }}">
                            @php
                                $upload = $vehicule->uploads->sortByDesc('id')->first();
                            @endphp

                            <div style="border-style: solid; background-color: {{ $vehicule->adtype === 1 ? '#FFEFD5' : '#FFFFFF' }} ">
                            <img src="/images/{{ $upload->resized_name }}" height="150" width="250"></a>


                        {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($vehicule->created_at)->diffForHumans()}} 
                            {{$vehicule->provincename}}
                          {{$vehicule->milage}}

                          </div>
<br>
                           <hr>

                    @endif

            @empty
                <td>No Advertisment to display.</td>
            @endforelse

</div>

</div>
</div>
{{ $vehicles->links() }}
</div>
@endsection
```

and I have set pagination with index blade file.

and this is SearchController@search function.

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
$vehicles =  Vehicle::search($request->get('search'))->orderBy('adtype','DESC')

            ->latest('updated_at')
            ->paginate(10);
        return view('vehicles.index', compact('vehicles'));
    }
```

but when I enter some values in the search input and enter search button

```
following error is occurred.
1/1) BadMethodCallException

Method latest does not exist.
```

how can fix this problem?

**edit dd result**

```
Builder {#375 ▼
  +model: Vehicle {#372 ▶}
  +query: "gampaha"
  +callback: null
  +index: null
  +wheres: []
  +limit: null
  +orders: array:1 [▶]
}
```

**updated Vehicle Model**

```
use Searchable;
     protected $guarded = [];

    public function searchableAs()
    {
        return 'categoryname';
    }
```

Comment: remove `->latest('updated_at')` and try again.

Comment: actually I need ->latest('updated_at') because I need print latest updated_at top of the page. it is satisfy my business rules

Comment: What's the result of `dd(Vehicle::search($request->get('search'))->orderBy('adtype','DESC'));`?

Comment: show your routes - `web.php`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir its **Builder {#375 ▼
  +model: Vehicle {#372 ▶}
  +query: "gampaha"
  +callback: null
  +index: null
  +wheres: []
  +limit: null
  +orders: array:1 [▶]
}
**

Comment: @Hamelraj **Route::get('search','SearchController@search');**

Comment: Please add the whole exception stacktrace.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir please see my edit question above

Comment: `->latest('updated_at')` remove and try `orderBy()`

Comment: I need latest('updated_at') because in my app i need show top of the page latest updated ones

Comment: you cant pass column name like that for `latest()` check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and tell what you will get

```
Vehicle::where('column1', 'like', '%' . $request->get('search') . '%')->orWhere('column2', 'like', '%' . $request->get('search') . '%')->orderBy('adtype', 'DESC')   ->latest('updated_at')   ->paginate(10);
```

And Share your search method inside your Vehicle model.

Comment: well this is working for table one column name search, then how can I add all column names to the above code segments and see updated question for search method inside your Vehicle model

Comment: you can use 

`Vehicle::where('column1', 'like', '%' . $request->get('search') . '%')
orWhere('column2', 'like', '%' . $request->get('search') . '%')
->orderBy('adtype', 'DESC')
            ->latest('updated_at')
            ->paginate(10);`

Comment: got following error ** (1/1) FatalErrorException

syntax error, unexpected 'orWhere' (T_STRING)**

Comment: You have missed symbol -> 
`Vehicle::where('column1', 'like', '%' . $request->get('search') . '%')->` `orWhere('column2', 'like', '%' . $request->get('search') . '%') ->orderBy('adtype', 'DESC')`
` ->latest('updated_at') ->paginate(10);`